# Passing a json array to a REST Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

This is a 2 part question.

1. I would like to pass an array of int values to my REST url but I'm getting an inline constraint exception. The route I tried to defined is as follows

[Route("categories/{categoryId:int}/documenttypes/{documentTypes:int[]}")]

...
...

and when called, it would look like this:

```
   api/categories/2/documenttypes/{[2,3,4,5]}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to handle this in-line constraint exception. I have found a few articles but none seem to apply on how to handle an array of int values.

Maybe it is not do-able and I should just change this to a POST request but I thought I'd try it with a GET first or just use the string parameter and just add another resource definition to my REST url such as

```
   api/config/categories/2/documenttypes/multi?doctype={[1,3,4]}
```

2. Is this event acceptable in terms of REST standards?

   ```
   api/categories/2/documenttypes/{[1,3,4]}
   ```

I know I could just pass it as a query string but the problem I have with that is that I ended up with 2 endpoints conflicting if I do this:

```
    api/categories/2/documenttypes
```

no parameters and returns all document types for the given category

```
    api/categories/2/documenttypes?doctypes={[1,2,3]}
```

When defined and then called, I get an error that there are multiple end point with the same definition, thus the request to see if I could somehow pass it as an inline contraint.

Hope the above makes sense. If not, ask away. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming the action is

```
[HttpGet("~/api/categories/{id}/documenttypes")]
public ActionResult GetDocs(int id, int[] doctype)
{
         if(doctype.Length >  0)
         {
            ....

          } else ...
}
```

use this url

```
api/categories/2/documenttypes?doctype=2&doctype=3&doctype=4&doctype=5
```

Comment: You missed the part where I said there was a duplicate conflict using this method as 2 endpoints would end up having the same route

Comment: @Thierry Parameters don't change the route

Comment: I'll check it out again later but when I have api/categories/2/documenttypes, it need to return all document types, and when I specify api/categories/2/documenttypes?doctype=1&doctype=2, etc... I should only get these returned. Is it just a case of checking if a parameter has been provided or not and call a different service function based on this?

Comment: @Thierry I added array check to my code

Comment: Great! I get hopefully get rid of this over bloated code :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the various parts that needed to be changed.

1. First, I had to add a new route constraint (`IHttpRouteConstraint`) to handle the new data type passed as part of the Web API REST resource:

   ```
    public class HttpRouteConstraintIntArray : IHttpRouteConstraint
    {
         public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route,
           string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values,
           HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
         {
             object value;
             if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
             {
                 var parameters = value.ToString()
                     .Replace("{", string.Empty)
                     .Replace("}", string.Empty)
                     .Replace("[", string.Empty)
                     .Replace("]", string.Empty);
                 var type = typeof(int);
                 var newvalues = parameters.Split(new[] { "," },
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                 
                 .Select(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type)
                 .ConvertFromString).ToArray();

                 var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(type, newvalues.Length);

                 newvalues.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);

                 return true;    
             }

             return false;
         }
    }
   ```

Once I declared this new constraint, I also had to register it in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("intarray", 
           typeof(HttpRouteConstraintIntArray));
```

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

But once I made these stanges, I started to get another error:

```
    the request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header
    get request ....
```

2. In order to resolve this error, I had to add [FromUri] in the endpoint definition:

   ```
   [HttpGet]  [Route("categories/{categoryId:int}/documenttypes/
              {documentTypeIds:intarray}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDataByDocumentTypeIds(
    int categoryId,[FromUri] int[] documentTypeIds)
   ```

Now the above is getting passed these 2 errors but some reason, the documentTypeIds is coming back as an array, but it only contains one value instead of 3 for example and its value is 0 instead of 1, so clearly need to add something else.

3. To handle the last problem, I had to create an action filter attribute:

   ```
    public class ArrayInputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    private readonly string[] _parameternames;

    public string Separator { get; set; }

    public ArrayInputAttribute(params string[] parameternames)
    {
        this._parameternames = parameternames;
        Separator = "-";
    }

    public void ProcessArrayInput(HttpActionContext actionContext, string parametername)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionArguments
              .ContainsKey(parametername))
        {
            var parameterdescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterName == parametername);

            if (parameterdescriptor != null && parameterdescriptor.ParameterType.IsArray)
            {
                var type = parameterdescriptor.ParameterType.GetElementType();
                var parameters = string.Empty;
                if (actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values
                      .ContainsKey(parametername))
                {
                    parameters = (string)actionContext.ControllerContext
                      .RouteData.Values[parametername];
                }
                else
                {
                    var queryString = actionContext.ControllerContext
                       .Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
                    if (queryString[parametername] != null)
                    {
                        parameters = queryString[parametername];
                    }
                }

                parameters = parameters.ToString()
                    .Replace("{", string.Empty)
                    .Replace("}", string.Empty)
                    .Replace("[", string.Empty)
                    .Replace("]", string.Empty);

                var values = parameters.Split(new[] { Separator },
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   Select(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).
                   ConvertFromString).ToArray();

                var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(type, values.Length);

                values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);

                actionContext.ActionArguments[parametername] = typedValues;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        foreach (var parameterName in _parameternames)
        {
            ProcessArrayInput(actionContext, parameterName);
        }
    }
   }
   ```

and lastly, I had to add the attribute to the endpoint definition:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("categories/{categoryId:int}/documenttypes/
            {documentTypeIds:intarray}")]
    [ArrayInputAttribute("documentTypeIds", Separator = ",")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDataByDocumentTypeIds(int categoryId,
    [FromUri] int[] documentTypeIds)
    {
    }
```

A few notes:

1. Some of the lines were split in order to be displayed semi decently in stackoverflow and clearly will not work in .NET studio
2. The above code was a combination of a couple of articles I eventually found after more googling. These are:

-[Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](http://%20https://newbedev.com/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

By the looks of things, I may not even need to Constraint, thought right now I don't have time to investigate as I need to move on, I will post an update when I do try it later.

[Web API Attribute Routing Route Constraints](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/web-api-route-constraints-attribute-routing/)

[Web API Attribute Routing Route Constrains](https://csharptechtics.blogspot.com/2020/07/web-api-attribute-routing-route.html)

Hope the above helps others.

Thanks.